# Which jQuery plugin animates an element by sliding it across the page to a 'target' element?

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-animate, move

Hay, I'm looking for a jQuery plugin which i've seem before but can't now find it.

It animates a div and makes it look like it is being sent to another div, imagine that you click 'buy' on an item and the item appears to moved across the screen to a shopping basket.

Any ideas what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [this](http://www.jscodetips.com/use-jquery-to-move-objects-horizontally-with-different-speed-3.html) would help:

```
var elements = {
  'div1' : { start: 10, distance: 100, duration: 1500},
  'div2' : { start: 30, distance: 600, duration: 1000}
}
$('.box').each(function (k, v) {
  var i = elements[v.id];
  $(v).css('left', i.start + 'px')
    .animate({left: (i.start + i.distance) + 'px'}, i.duration);
});
```